# Ionic 2 disable swipe back without nav-bar

Tags: javascript, ionic2

In Ionic 2, I haven't found a way to disable swipe to go back. I have injected both NavController and ViewController without finding any function that disables this.

The component is full-screen, so I can't use the attributes of nav-bar to disable it.

SOLUTION:

My app.ts contains a -tag. I simply added swipeBackEnabled="false" to it and it disabled swipe-back for all my pages.

Thanks in advance, 
Markus

Answer (score 0):

I would leave this as a comment if I had the rep (50). Have you taken a look at [this thread?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-disable-the-swipe-in-ion-menu/49587)
Something like this could go in your constructor:

```
this.menu = menu;
this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this(by injecting MenuController), but it seem to disable a menu that has similar behaviour, not the back-action.